# how to group dates per week and then value count them

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

i have a data set with dates and values in other column.
I want to group then 7 dates and then value count them.
Current value_count give some output like below.
df_clean.CreationDate.value_counts()

df_clean.CreationDate.value_counts()

```
df_clean.CreationDate.value_counts()
```

```
Output now look like this
04/01/2019    133
07/01/2019     95
04/02/2019     90
06/11/2019     86
01/07/2019     81
04/03/2019     81
22/07/2019     73
03/04/2019     72
14/01/2019     68
28/01/2019     66
04/08/2019     66
18/02/2019     66
24/06/2019     65
01/08/2019     64
06/03/2019     63
02/04/2019     63
01/11/2019     62
15/07/2019     61
02/11/2019     61
02/05/2019     59
14/02/2019     59
16/01/2019     58
23/07/2019     57
27/05/2019     54
20/05/2019     54
18/03/2019     54
17/01/2019     53
25/02/2019     53
23/04/2019     53
07/08/2019     53
```

I want it to look like this or similar

```
1/1/2019 - 7/1/2019 333
8/1/2019 - 14/1/2019 232
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a datetime column in python:

```
df_clean.resample('W').sum()
```

this assumes that your datastructure is:

```
CreationDate 
04/01/2019
05/01/2019
...
```

If CreationDate is not a datetime object, you can convert it with and then:

```
df_clean['CreationDate']= pd.to_datetime(df_clean['CreationDate'])
df_clean['CreationDate'].value_counts().resample('W').sum()
```

This will give you the outcome per week

Comment: ```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'
I get this error . my datatype is datetime tough
i have column name "CreationDate" and multiple enteries of same date. i want to count how many enteries are submitted on each day and week.

Comment: you can check it with `df_clean.dtypes`

Comment: CreationDate     6113 non-null datetime64[ns]

Comment: I solved it by creating a new column and assigning value from  `pd.DatetimeIndex(df_clean['CreationDate']).weekofyear `